# Mutt Jump to an index number and view message

Tags: mutt

At the moment, to see a particular message, I type its index number, press enter, and press enter again to open the selected message.

Is it possible to write a macro so that after entering the number followed by enter, mutt opens the selected message (as opposed to simply selecting it?).

Thank you for your help in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with macros: Mutt macros don't allow input at the time of the macro being run, so there's no way for the macro to access the number you are typing in.

Source: [Mutt Guide: Macros](https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/Macros)

> Macros are a way to save keystrokes in mutt. Basically you can do everything you would enter interactively in a macro, too. With one exception: *You can't prompt the user for input.* [my italics]